# When creating an event listener, function is firing right away

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a function that when clicking on an image, it will add an event listener to another image.  When creating the event listener, myFunction() is being called right away and not waiting for the click on #firstStep

```
  function firstImageClick(){
   //add event listener 
    document.getElementById("firstStep").addEventListener("click", myFunction());
  }
```

Comment: Remove the parenthesis from `myFunction()` in 2nd parameter of `addEventListener()`. Including the parenthesis will invoke your function immediately. Proper code should look like this: `document.getElementById("firstStep").addEventListener("click", myFunction);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding the `myFunction` as callback, but the return of the call to `myFunction`.

You must pass the function, not invoke it:

```
enfunction firstImageClick(){
    //add event listener 
    document.getElementById("firstStep").addEventListener("click",    myFunction);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameter should be `myFunction` instead of `myFunction()`.

Answer (score 1):

call that function like below

```
function firstImageClick(){
   //add event listener 
   document.getElementById("firstStep").addEventListener("click", 
   myFunction);
}
```

remove parenthesis from `myFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis make the function fire straight away.  Change the end of your snippet by taking out the parenthesis.
`("click", myFunction());` to `("click", myFunction);`